# How can i change the image upload directory and view image url in laravel

Tags: laravel, image, url, directory, rename

In my script all images uploaded goes into directory "ib" but i want to change that directory to a different name eg. "imgib"

here is what i did so far. i changed the code vlues from "ib" to "imgib"

```
                } else {
                    // upload path
                    $path = 'imgib/';
                    // if path not exists create it
                    if (!File::exists($path)) {
                        File::isDirectory($path) or File::makeDirectory($path, 0777, true, true);
                    }
                    // move image to path
                    $upload = $request->file('uploads')->move($path, $imageName);
                    // file name
                    $filename = url($path) . '/' . $imageName;
                    // method server host
                    $method = 1;
                }
                // if image uploded
                if ($upload) {
                    // if user auth get user id
                    if (Auth::user()) {$userID = Auth::user()->id;} else { $userID = null;}
                    // create new image data
                    $data = Image::create([
                        'user_id' => $userID,
                        'image_id' => $string,
                        'image_path' => $filename,
                        'image_size' => $fileSize,
                        'method' => $method,
                    ]);
                    // if image data created
                    if ($data) {
                        // success array
                        $response = array(
                            'type' => 'success',
                            'msg' => 'success',
                            'data' => array('id' => $string),
                        );
                        // success response
                        return response()->json($response);
                    } else {
                        if (file_exists('imgib/' . $filename)) {$delete = File::delete('imgib/' . $filename);}
                        // error response
                        return response()->json(array(
                            'type' => 'error',
                            'errors' => 'Opps !! Error please refresh page and try again.',
                        ));
                    }
```

so far everything looks ok and it creates "imgib" directory automatically and all uploads go into "imgib" directory.

But the issue is, image url still uses the same old directory name.

eg. site.org/ib/78huOP09vv

How to make it get the correct url eg. site.org/imgib/78huOP09vv

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone. I managed to fix the issue by editing `viewimage.blade.php`

Yes of course need to clear the browser cache after editing the files.